# How to show the search results records updated count in UI page in angular

Tags: angular, search, filter, count, ngfor

I have a table, fetching the records through API, displaying the records using ngFor in the table. The total records count is also displayed. I am filtering the table by entering keywords in search input and the records get filtered. But the filtered record count is not getting updated.

```
<div class="table-filter-options">
    <div class="search-bar-div">
        <div class="search-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="Search...">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paginationDiv">
    <div class="pagination-div">
        <pagination-controls class="text-right" (pageChange)="pageNumber = $event"></pagination-controls>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        <span class="totalCount">{{prodcuts?.length}} Records</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabl table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header">S.No</th>
                <th class="header">Product Number</th>
                <th class="header">Company Name</th>
                <th class="header">Created Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngIf="prodcuts?.length">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of prodcuts | filter:term   | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: pageNumber }; count as c; let i = index">
                <tr class="cursor">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{item?.product_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{item?.company_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item?.created_date | date :'short'}}</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[TS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uXNP.png)
[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Oet.png)
I searched for the filter pipe but there is no any custom pipe in the application.
If anyone can help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a getter in your component:

```
get totalItemsCount(): number {
   return this.products.length
}
```

and display it in your template instead of `{{prodcuts?.length}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created getter in component and called totalItemsCount() in template. But it is printed as string. Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: please add screenshot

Comment: I have attached screenshots to my question. I can see the actual count now but it is not getting updated when the records are filtered.